# Constructor Initialization Lists for Multidimensional array

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I tried to initialize all data in the member array to `0`

```
class Array {
    int m_anArray1D[10];
    int m_anArray2D[10][10];
public:
    Array(): m_anArray1D{0}, m_anArray2D{{0}} {}
};
```

but the codes will never be working.

Is there anyway to assign all data inside a 2D array **at once**?

Comment: you don't give any type to your members

Comment: And you forgot the parantheses -> m_anArray1D({0})

Comment: oh right, that was a typing error, thx for remind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! you can use `fill` in the constructor

`std::fill(m_anArray2d[0]+0,m_anArray2d[9]+10,0);`

Or use `memset`

```
memset(m_anArray2D, 0, sizeof(int)*10*10);
```

Or

```
class Array {
    int m_anArray1D[10];
    int m_anArray2D[10][10];
public:
    Array(): m_anArray1D(), m_anArray2D() {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code has a typographical error and you have not provided your compiler version, the following code would be sufficient for all compilers supporting C++98.

```
struct Array {
    int m_anArray1D[10];
    int m_anArray2D[10][10];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Array arr = {};
    return 0;
}
```